# Php Array not displaying - limit of MySQL Values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I need to know If php, mysql or even my script has a limit of values or memory, or something that doesn't show me all the values of my database table.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$sql = "SELECT id_team,name FROM teams ORDER BY id_team LIMIT 50;";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('id_team'=>$row[0],'name'=>$row[1]));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If I run this script with the LIMIT 50 condition, it works, but when I change the limit to 70 or more It doesn't work anymore and doesn't print me anything. I don't know if there is like a limit of memory or values or something. Can someone help me please?

This is my output when I use Limite 5 (for example):

> {"result":[{"id_team":"3","name":"Tonkas"},{"id_team":"4","name":"Combis"},{"id_team":"5","name":"Looney
>   Tunes"},{"id_team":"6","name":"Bullets"},{"id_team":"7","name":"Valkiry"}]}

I use a counter inside the loop and It always return me the number of the LIMIT I give in the condition, If I give LIMIT 100, the counter prints me 100, but I don't get anything from the array.
PHP Version 5.6.29 & JSON version 1.2.1 - Hosted in 1and1

**SOLVED**
It was the codification (charset) when the loop found a invalid character (in this case letter 'ñ') it just break and didn't continue filling the array, just set the charset and worked:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
```

Comment: When you put limit 70 does your query execute ?.. Check if returns false

Comment: No, It doesn't. Just confirmed with a condition, it returns me true.

Comment: Can you print_r($result) just before you are creating the json_encode ?

Comment: if you are using phpmyadmin or from sql console run that query and see if it returns 70 rows. If not then of-course it will blank

Comment: can you try "SELECT id_team,name FROM teams ORDER BY id_team LIMIT 0, 70"

Comment: Are you trying web service?

Comment: Don't give limit and check what's the count of results you are getting ?

Comment: Try in phpmyadmin with your query and see if it returns any results.

Comment: @Sk_ Yes I can, and still throws me true.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I run it on mysql console and returns me all of them, (135 aprox)

Comment: @Naincy It's the same problem works with less than 70 results only.

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran Yes, Im using web service for an android app.

Comment: @rahul_m I used a counter in the loop and throws me the total of the rows in my table (135)

Comment: @HarshBarach Yes I get all of the results (135 aprox).

Comment: What if you try 69 or 71 ? What you are getting ?

Comment: did any error populate @Becerra95

Comment: Enable error_reporting with ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL); and post your error in your question

Comment: @rahul_m Works on 69 and doesn't works in 71

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran I enabled them and I don't receive any error...

Comment: How did you get true while you are printing $result? Bcoz you are assigned $result as an array then your are pushing another array into that. If you are getting all the results in the $result array then the problem might be in the json_encode function. Check the name contains any single quote

Comment: @Sk_ I just use and if for the query ($res variable) and it returns me a True.

Comment: @Sk_ Found the mistake, It's for the codification, it breaks the values when in a name has a "Ñ". So probable I'll have to set a charset before